# Detecting when a process has finished (but not exited)

Tags: bash, exit, polling

I have a program that's run in unix (that I have no control over) that when finished prints 'Completed successfully' but does not exit. I want to automatically detect when the process finishes (by checking the output of the command), so that I can kill the process and so that I can proceed do other activities. The complexity comes because I want to be able to run multiples of these scripts concurrently. (One activity I need to do requires the script to be called with various inputs, but each time the script runs it takes a while to return, and so I want to do them in parallel)

Has anyone done something similar to this?
I could redirect the stderr and stdout output of the command to a temporary file which has a random file name, then tail the file and pipe to grep for the end conditions (I.e. the certain log lines). The problem is, surely tail -f would keep running, and so it would never exit. Should I poll? If so, what's the best approach?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm running on an old Solaris machine which has bash 2.x; no expect; and it looks like I have no grep --max-count=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn /home/foo/myjob
expect "Completed successfully"

Comment: I don't think this actually kills the process, I believe expect wait for all spawned processes to finish after sending them a SIGHUP. From the original question I gathered that this is a misbehaving program, so a SIGHUP will probably not do a lot...

Though one could of course grab the PID that the spawn returns and run an exec kill after the expect.

Comment: @wich Even if that's true, the process would have to be going out of it's way to handle sighup. But sure, you can explicitly send any signal you like. I just think expect handles the waiting for "Completed successfully" as elegantly as any approach I can think of.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to poll. You can use [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) tools, such as [inotifywait](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait), to detect when the output file has changed, and then grep it and kill the process if necessary. Happy hunting!

Comment: That looks very interesting. Unfortunately I'm running on an old Solaris machine :(

Answer (score 1):

Here's my stab at it, it works pretty well, but is rather spammy because each time kill is called a killed message echoing the entire subshell script is output to console and I can't seemt to supress it. I will update if I find a way to get rid of the spammyness, (by the way, redirecting stdout and stderr to /dev/null does not help.)

Note: You need bash4 to run this; `$BASHPID` is only available from 4 onwards, and `$$` is not an alternative because it gives the pid of the parent shell, not the subshell.

```
!/bin/bash

for i in {1..8}; do
  (
    mypid=$BASHPID
    (
      #subshell to simulate started process
      sleep 2
      echo finished
      while : ; do
        :
      done
    ) | \
    {
      while read line; do
        if [[ $line == finished ]]; then
          break;
        fi
      done
      echo process done, killing $mypid...
      kill -9 $mypid
    }
  ) &
done
wait
```

Answer (score 1):

The following wrapper script will call your real command, piping output to *tee* which will write to a fifo. The wrapper script will kill your real command, when the expected string is *greped* from the fifo:

```
#!/bin/bash

# cmd to run
expected_output=$1
shift
cmd=("$@")
# where to read commands output
mkfifo /tmp/killonoutput.$$
# start cmd async 
"${cmd[@]}"|tee /tmp/killonoutput.$$ 2>/dev/null &

if grep -q --max-count=1 "$expected_output" /tmp/killonoutput.$$;then
    kill %1 
    echo "Killed ${cmd[@]}" 
fi
# grep returned so fifo was closed
rm  /tmp/killonoutput.$$
```

Sample execution:

```
./killonoutput.sh "Finished" bash -c "echo sleeping;sleep 3;echo Finished; sleep 10000" 
sleeping
Finished
Killed bash -c echo sleeping;sleep 3;echo Finished; sleep 10000
./killonoutput.sh: line 17: 19553 Terminated              "${cmd[@]}"
     19554                       | tee /tmp/killonoutput.$$ 2> /dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

this might be overkill for bash, maybe? if you were using python, you could use the `subprocess` module keep a communication channel open between your own program and your child scripts. even better, you could use the `threading` module to start multiple runs of the child script in parallel.

does the script output anything AFTER it outputs "completed successfully" ? if not, you could just poll for the last x characters it has outputed (to a random file like you suggested, maybe using `tail -n 1` to get the last line) and see if you just saw 'completed successfully'. but if the script keeps printing stuff afterwards, you might miss the line.

or you could `grep` for "completed successfully" in the output.

Answer (score 0):

A few random ideas. (1) If it's your program, you could modify it to indicate doneness more usefully. (2) Looking at the process list ( ps ax ) you should be able to see it go into an I/O wait when it tries to output the "Completed" message.  (3) I believe pseudo tty's exist for this purpose, that you can watch their stdout directly without having to muck about with temporary files.

Answer (score 0):

1st possible solution:
**your_program > tempfile1**
**grep -i "Completed successfully" tempfile1; if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then i=`pidof your_program`; kill $i; fi**

First is redirection. Second checks for the exit status of grep. If it is 0 (success) it gets the pid of your program and kills it.
This was a "think-fast" exercise. It should work. A drawback is that you can only run one instance of your program at a time, but of course an adaptation can be made and you could run it in parallel.

edit-27.05.2010:
2nd possible solution:
**tail --pid=`pidof your_program` -f -n0 tempfile1 | awk '/Completed/ {if ($1=="Completed") {system("i=`pidof your_program`; kill $i")}}' &**

Well, with this long line you don't need a loop/crontab anymore. Explanation:
--pid=`pidof your_program` makes tail die after the specified PID is ended. This way, when the program gets killed, tail dies along with it.
-n0 ignores other "Completed" statements in tempfile1 (so you don't have to worry to always truncate tempfile1 first).
awk searches for the "Completed" statement thrown out by your program and the `{system}` part executes the kill on your program.
Also don't forget the `&` at the end as it backgrounds the entire thing.
Have fun.

Comment: Indent your code by four spaces, it will then be formatted into a code block preserving indenting and line breaks.

Comment: I would need to do a loop though, right? If I didn't then if the 'Completed successfully' didn't arrive for a few minutes, the grep would fail. I like your concept though, since I seem to be fairly limited with the processes I have available.

Comment: Yes, a loop, or just add it in crontab at every minute.  
I also came up with another solution (I've edited my primary post because I can't format code in comments).

Comment: @wich ah, that was meant to be run directly in the CLI, it wasn't a script, that's why I didn't indent it.